# Cannot call show dialog() on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell, winforms, showdialog

I am trying to open the next page of my Winforms script and atm on first launch the error is get when clicking the next button is "you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" [void] $Form_UserInformation.ShowDialog() being the issue code here. When I run it the second time it runs fine but this doesn't work for an EXE file as it closes it and doesn't remember the previous session.

```
# HomePage Form

$Form_HomePage = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

    $Form_HomePage.text = "New User Script"
    $Form_HomePage.Size =  New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,400)
    $Form_HomePage.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
    $Form_HomePage.TopMost = $false
    $Form_HomePage.MaximizeBox = $false
    $Form_HomePage.MinimizeBox = $true
    $Form_HomePage.ControlBox = "true"
    $Form_HomePage.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $Form_HomePage.Font = "Segoe UI"

# Title label

$label_HomeTitle = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

    $label_HomeTitle.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(47,8)
    $label_HomeTitle.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,42)
    $label_HomeTitle.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI",24,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
    $label_HomeTitle.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $label_HomeTitle.Text = "Kuehne && Nagel"
    $Form_HomePage.Controls.Add($label_HomeTitle)

# Subheading label

$label_HomeSubTitle = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

    $label_HomeSubTitle.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,60)
    $label_HomeSubTitle.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,42)
    $label_HomeSubTitle.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI",16,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
    $label_HomeSubTitle.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $label_HomeSubTitle.Text = "New User Script"
    $Form_HomePage.Controls.Add($label_HomeSubTitle)

# Next button

$button_HomeStart = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

    $button_HomeStart.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,200)
    $button_HomeStart.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,32)
    $button_HomeStart.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $button_HomeStart.Text = "Start"
    $button_HomeStart.Add_Click({
        [void] $Form_UserInformation.ShowDialog()
        $Form_HomePage.Hide()
    })
    $Form_HomePage.Controls.Add($button_HomeStart)

# About button

$button_About = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

    $button_About.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,250)
    $button_About.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,32)
    $button_About.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $button_About.Text = "About"
    $button_About.Add_Click({
        
    })
    $Form_HomePage.Controls.Add($button_About)

# Exit button

$button_HomeExit = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

    $button_HomeExit.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,300)
    $button_HomeExit.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,32)
    $button_HomeExit.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $button_HomeExit.Text = "Exit"
    $button_HomeExit.Add_Click({
        $Form_HomePage.Close()
    })
    $Form_HomePage.Controls.Add($button_HomeExit)

# Show Form

$Form_HomePage.Add_Shown({$Form_HomePage.Activate()})

[void] $Form_HomePage.ShowDialog()

# User Information Form

$Form_UserInformation = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

    $Form_UserInformation.text = "New User Script"
    $Form_UserInformation.Size =  New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,400)
    $Form_UserInformation.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
    $Form_UserInformation.TopMost = $false
    $Form_UserInformation.MaximizeBox = $false
    $Form_UserInformation.MinimizeBox = $true
    $Form_UserInformation.ControlBox = "true"
    $Form_UserInformation.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $Form_UserInformation.Font = "Segoe UI"
```

Comment: Nowhere in your script is a variable `$Form_UserInformation` defined. Why do you expect it to contain a form control?

Comment: Try `[void]$Script:Form_UserInformation.ShowDialog()`

Comment: Same issue with that added bit of code

Comment: Are you creating User Information Form *before* opening the main form?

Comment: PowerShell interprets from top to bottom, so if you defined the secondary form `$Form_UserInformation` **below** the line where you call `$Form_HomePage.ShowDialog()`, then the first time around there is no `$Form_UserInformation` yet..

Comment: The main form is the home page, from there I am opening the user information form, the user information form is below the home page code. Should I move the home page form to the bottom of the code then maybe so everything has a chance to run before loading the first form? I thought it would run through the code first, then start at the top so it knows the variables.

Comment: You should probably move the call to `[void] $Form_HomePage.ShowDialog()` to the very bottom - otherwise the rest of the script won't execute until _after_ you close it